# Maven clean install strange download

Tags: java, maven

I have been using maven for a while, since a couple of weeks I started to notice some downloads every time I execute "clean install".

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/qpid/proton-jms/0.3.0-fuse-2/proton-jms-0.3.0-fuse-2.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo/org/apache/qpid/proton-jms/0.3.0-fuse-2/proton-jms-0.3.0-fuse-2.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/release/org/apache/qpid/proton-jms/0.3.0-fuse-2/proton-jms-0.3.0-fuse-2.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/release/org/apache/qpid/proton/0.3.0-fuse-2/proton-0.3.0-fuse-2.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/release/org/apache/qpid/proton-api/0.3.0-fuse-2/proton-api-0.3.0-fuse-2.pom
```

I'm guessing that someone add a new dependency into the POM file (maybe spring) but still, it should download just one time right? it is downloading every time for me,

Any suggestions to get rid of this ?

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct. The downloading should occur only once if you don't delete your local repository.

Comment: Have you checked your maven update policy?

Comment: All these link return 404, I guess this have to do with the reason Maven try to download them over and over.

Comment: The versions which are mentioned are simply wrong. If i check Central i can not see a version `0.3.0-fuse-2` ...see here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/qpid/proton-jms/

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope I haven noticed this, maybe it's related

Answer (score 1):

Its not actually download all the dependency from the Internet. If first time issued a `mvn`  command the dependencies mentioned in `pom.xml` are downloaded from Internet and are saved in your local M2_HOME or local repository. Then if you don't remove these dependencies from the M2_HOME or local repository every next `mvn` command get/fetch these dependencies from the M2_HOME or local repository.

Maven also display this getting/fetching of jar file as download. You may notice the the later download takes much less time than the first download. Because the later `mvn` command download/get/fetch these dependencies from he local repository.

Comment: I never delete files from the M2_HOME directory